# A two-headed snake that would bite and belch

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> My prefix is a medium;
>   Or a substance without colour
>   Whose suffix isn’t male;
>   It is used to refer the other
>
> My suffix is a totality
>   Of what remains on one side
>   It is also a facility
>   Which I am used to provide

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may refer to the

> Ethernet - the title describing the cable heads for input & output.

My prefix is a medium; Or a substance without colour

> Ether is a medium such as an atmosphere. In chemistry it's a colourless liquid.

Whose suffix isn’t male; It is used to refer the other

> Her refers to a female.

My suffix is a totality, Of what remains on one side

> Net is what remains after deductions, or the catch.

It is also a facility, Which I am used to provide

> The Internet is accessed by Ethernet cable on a wired network.

Comment: Congrats on 50k rep!

Answer (score 4):

The poem describes a

> VACUUM CLEANER

My prefix is a medium;

> A physical vacuum (lack of matter) can be a medium for light waves.

Or a substance without colour

> A physical vacuum is colorless.

Whose suffix isn't male;

> -um is a Latin suffix for some neuter nouns in the nominative case.

It is used to refer the other

> The English word "vacuum" is commonly used as short for "vacuum cleaner".

My suffix is a totality
Of what remains on one side

> After a vacuum cleaner is used, the target surface is left "cleaner".

It is also a facility
Which I am used to provide

> The purpose of a vacuum cleaner is of course to facilitate cleaning.

The question title, "a two-headed snake that would bite and belch", seems to ring a bell as from some work of literature, movie, etc., that might be relevant, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: A worthy attempt, but the [tag:word] tag indicates that the answer is a single word in this context, and the title does have a significance to the answer.